# Nuxt/Strapi/Shopify-API: decrease nuxt app loading time when loading data on init

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, shopify, strapi, shopify-storefront-api

I have just published my app, including a **Nuxt.js** Frontend, a **Strapi** CMS and **Headless Shopify** for checkout management. To achieve a global cart component I need to load all the products on init, like in the following part. The data is coming from the CMS.

**./plugins/products.js**

```
// Load products on init

export default async ({app}) => {
  await app.store.dispatch('shop/products/setProducts');
}
```

**./store/products.js**

```
export const actions = {
  async setProducts(state) {
    const allProducts = await this.$axios.$get('/products');
    state.commit('setProducts', allProducts);
  },
```

The CMS is getting data from the Shopify Storefront API via GraphQL/Apollo Client like this:

./controllers/product.js

```
  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.product.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.product.find(ctx.query);
    }

    for (entity of entities) {
      const graphId = btoa('gid://shopify/Product/' + entity.shopifyId);
      try {
        await client.query({
          query: gql`
                  query {
                    node(id: "${graphId}") {
                      ... on Product {
                        id
                        title
                        productType
                        variants(first: 250) {
                          edges {
                            node {
                              title
                              id
                              availableForSale
                              sku
                              priceV2 {
                                amount
                                currencyCode
                              }
                              compareAtPriceV2 {
                                amount
                                currencyCode
                              }
                              requiresShipping
                              selectedOptions {
                                name
                                value
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }`
        }).then((product) => {
          entity.shopify = {
            id: product.data.node.id,
            product_type: product.data.node.id,
            variants: product.data.node.variants,
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    return entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, {model: strapi.models.product}));
  },
  },
```

**apollo settings:**

```
const ApolloClient = require('apollo-boost').default;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {InMemoryCache, gql} = require('apollo-boost');

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://santras.myshopify.com/api/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  fetch: fetch,
  headers: {
    'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': 'e908298c617e035c47c62ae449887b3c'
  }
});
```

The biggest problem is, that loading all the products and variants from the shopify api is very slow. the first load without caching of all products takes up to 20000ms. after caching, every request of `/products` takes up to 1.500 seconds.

Now, a lot of test users are experiencing a long loading time of the nuxt app, because of this. there is a nuxt loading circle for 5-10 seconds, before something is showing. Is there a way, to already show the content, while the data from the plugin is loading?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the [Fetch Hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/) in Nuxt. This enables to fetch async data.
On the component side it exposes **$fetchState** whith the following states with in particular **$fetchState.pending** which is true while the fetching is ongoing. It allows you to place some data while waiting to get the data back from API.

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching data from Shopify ...</div>
  <div v-else>
   <div v-for="product in products" ... />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   products: []
  }
 },
 async fetch() {
  this.products= await strapi.services.product.search(this.query);
 }
}
</script>
```